# Is is possible to send information and receive a response through wcf/webservice to a website from a wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send some data to my mvc4 website from my wpf app and received data back from the website back to my wpf application.  I tried to find a solution before coming here and people were saying something about a web service should be able to do that, but I dont know if i need to make a web service in my mvc4 website or if I need to make a wcf project in my wpf app.

Any guides or tutorials about this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:This is what I ended up with after seeing the first solution it does not work at the moment, I am not sure why im not getting a proper response back.

```
public bool GetData(LoginObj loginObj)
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:12611/");

    // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Home/VerifyLogin",loginObj).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       var users = response.Content;
       if (users.ToString() == "true")
           return true;
       else
           return false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

this is in the home controller below

```
public class LoginObj
{
   public string username { get; set; }
   public string password { get; set; }
   public LoginObj(string username, string password)
   {
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
   }
}
public JsonResult VerifyLogin(LoginObj loginObj)
{
   bool isValid = true;

   isValid = System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(loginObj.username, loginObj.password);

   return Json(isValid,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but normally a web application (mvc4) calls the service. Whatever to send, receive or both.

There you have your web app call the wcf requesting data and if it's changed elsewhere it will be returned from the wcf no matter what. When you need to save data you just send it to the wcf.

If you need some notification/chat-like app so a WCF can push data to your web app, seems like you are looking for SignalR.

If you can, please expand or explain better your question/need.

**UPDATE:**

You can create a 'web service' (wcf or webapi) or using the already mvc application and return a json response to act like a web service.

The simple you can get is something like :

A new action in your mvc app

```
public JsonResult CanLogin(string username, string password){
    bool isValid = true; // check if username & password are ok and return True or False
    return Json(isValid);
}
```

then on your wpf create an httpclient and call /application/CanLogin with user and password

*you can allowGet on the json response for testing in your browser.*

```
    return Json(isValid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: i need to send login info to the website that can do the verifiying  with its database and return a true or false, so the person can log in to the wpf app

Comment: where would I put this json response in my mvc website?

Comment: Seems to be really insecure to me

Comment: @Anarion you can have the same security as a login form on your page. It's doesn't matter how you make your request. From a security stand-point what's the different to do a form request to your login action ?

Comment: @imGreg you can do it in any controller you want. If it's on an account controller, the call would be `http://domain.com/Account/CanLogin`

Comment: @Bart, I was taling about your particular example, because it seemed like imGreg is going to use your code.

Comment: @Anarion my particular example is just fine and secure as a Login action is.

Comment: @Bart I made some progress and I updated my original post with the both calls from both sides. I am not getting any bool value on the wpf side and im not sure why

Comment: I'm not sure how LoginObj will be serialized. Do you declare it twice in wpf and mvc? they have different namespaces? try to access via your browser and see if you get a response. Also, try change the action in your mvc to receive simple types first (like string)